# Solutions to easy Diophantine $8pq +1 = a^{2}$, p and q primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Show that $p = 3$ and $p = 5$ are the only primes with a maximal $3$ solutions each to $8pq + 1 = a^2$, where $p$ and $q$ are prime.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't true. For example, with $p=11$, you can take $q = 5$ or $q=23$.

Comment: Ok Cocopuffs you´re right. I should have asked: Show that 3 is the only prime p such that there are 3 primes q  that satisfy 8pq +1 =a ^2.

Comment: Still no. For $p=5$ you can take $q=2$, $q=3$ or $q = 11$.

Comment: You are again right Cocopuffs and killing me sofly with your words (that´s sense of humor and just a song). I should have excluded 5 also.

Comment: @user55514 Ok - it looks better now; no counterexamples for primes at least up to $10000$.

Comment: Yes, Cocopuffs, no counterexample up to 100000, as for me, with Pari gp, and also an elemental short proof that 3 and 5 are the only such primes with as much as 3 solutions.

Comment: Wait --- are you saying you *have* a short proof that $3$ and $5$ etc., etc., or are you still asking for one?